# Spring Boot context-path doesn't return index.html in tests

Tags: spring-boot, testing, contextpath

I want to test that GET "/" returns index.html (Which is the case in a build) but when I try that in an integration test I get 404 NOT FOUND. Here's how I test:

```java
mvc.perform(get("/"));
```

application.properties:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/
```

Again, this works as expected with a browser/REST client.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it makes no sense to me, the problem was the accept type - application/json. Changed it to */* and it worked